# Confirmation Pattern deleting a comment in Google Suite

Tags: interaction-design, modal-windows

**Context**

I would like information about the current pattern to delete a comment from an app of the Google Suite.

**Where and How to find it**

Remove a comment made in Google Docs, Google Sheets, etc.

[image: Google Sheet Confirmation Dialog. It says "Delete this comment thread?" with two buttons (Delete and Cancel)]

**Questions**

1. What's the name for this mini-modal window that Google is using for removing comments?
2. What're the benefits of using this instead of a modal window? and when we should use one over the other??

**Concerns**

My guess is that they are looking for a way to have the confirmation UI closer to the action button (Fitts's Law). But, certainly, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

## Dialog

> A dialog is an overlay that requires the user to interact with it and designed to elicit a response from the user. Dialogs inform users about critical information, require users to make decisions, or involve multiple tasks. Within apps, on the web and even on mobile dialogs are increasingly used to direct the user’s attention to a specific task, without taking them away from the current screen.

[image]

[Source link](http://babich.biz/5-essential-ux-rules-for-dialog-design/)

Answer (score 0):

**Why we should using Dialog?**

Modal is better UX, because it isn't breaking the flow (don't redirect from current page) Currently, modules are placed within the modal(eg registration or login)

**Where we should using Dialog?**

Usually, we use to confirm the action, often destructive or with high priority or an action that can't be undone.

I advise read this article - https://uxplanet.org/5-essential-ux-rules-for-dialog-design-4de258c22116

There are a lot of good practises and extensive knowledge in the subject.